# How can I mask or park my url "example1.com" with this other "example2.com" in virtualmin?

Tags: domains, redirects, virtualhost, masking, alias

I want `example2.com` to always appear in the address bar and show the content of my site `example1.com`.

I applied this solution, but if I enter `example2.com`, it redirects to `example1.com` but the address appears as `example1.com`.

https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/tutorial/how-to-create-virtual-server-alias/

In my `.htacccess` I have this code:

```
ReWriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) example1.com/$1 [P]

ReWriteRule ^sitemap/list_([0-9]+).xml$ user-uploads/sitemap/list_$1.xml [L]

ReWriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ user-uploads/sitemap.xml [L]
```

What can I do? I need `example2.com` to appear in the address bar, and always show the content of `example1.com`.

Comment: Is that really what you want? Showing the same content for two different domains is bad for branding and horrible for SEO.

Comment: Somebody voted to move this to Server Fault, however, they don't accept questions about managing domains and sites through virtualmin or cpanel. Questions there must be about managing servers (like having root access to the server.) It looks to me like this question is about websites, so it would be fine here.